# Can keyboard have done and cancel buttons?

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard

Im trying to create a password page similar to the one that opens up when you click Lock+wallpaper in the settings of the Windows Phone.

How ever I could not find a keyboard with the done and cancel, a done and cancel buttons along with the numeric keyboard is visible in the lock+wallpaper page when you toggle the password switch.

How do I get one similar to that? As as alternative I tried to create done and cancel buttons, but the problem is, the keyboard overlaps these buttons where as in the lock+wallpaper page, the keyboard stays and does not overlap the button.This should mean that the buttons are present along with the keyboard right?

Could anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no InputScope which add "done" or "cancel" buttons to the SIP.
Instead you should look to use the ApplicationBar and add buttons  for each of these functions. FOr doen you could use an image of a tick or a save icon for "done" and a cross for "cancel".

Be careful not to add a Cancel button if you really don't need one as the hardware back button would suffice instead.

Comment: +1 I'm wondering why MS decided to use extra buttons for "Done" and "Cancel" in the first place. I get the feeling that there is no app bar available in the settings dialog.

Comment: yeaa, i kinda realised tht. I have created a app bar with done and cancel :) and this lwhich looks like the only way to get it done  :) thanks anyways.

Comment: It's also very annoying that left and right we're being teased with certain ways of implementing things only to find out that we can't do the same thing.